# Are "loops" a type of "Conditional Statement" in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I have a project that reads: "There will be no conditional statements (if, switch, or,…)." I'm not sure if this includes `for` and `while` loops, since both technically run on conditions. Could I get away with saying that they're "conditional loops" instead?

Comment: Depends entirely on the stipulations of your project.  You can call them whatever you want; check with whomever is in charge to make sure they'll agree with your definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably be acceptable to use loops (`for`, `while`,...), but you would need to check with the project author. I tend to treat loops and conditional statements separately, as they usually have different purposes...

- Conditional statements like `if` and `switch` will make a choice out of a list of options. They only run once.
- Loops like `for` and `while` are typically designed to run a piece of code multiple times.

Of course this is only a generalisation, and everyone probably has a different opinion, but I certainly treat them differently because they have different primary purposes.

For extra credit, Wikipedia seems to agree. The [If Statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_statement) is a conditional operator, and the [For Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop) is an iteration statement.

Comment: However, if the goal of the project is to avoid using conditions whatsoever, you can just replace `if (...) { foo() }` with, e.g. `while (...) { foo(); break; }`.

For a school assignment (which I assume this is, since the real world rarely makes random stipulations like this), *definitely* check with the professor first.

Comment: Exactly, you can easily use loops to simulate conditional statements, but you typically wouldn't do this unless you were trying to work around a specific requirement. Thus I agree, check with the project author first!

Answer (score 2):

`for` and `while` loops use (terminating) *conditions*, not conditional *statements*, so on that basis loops are OK.

Apart from loops, another option would be the [ternary operator `?`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) - it's not a *statement*, it's an *operator*, and you may be able to code some conditional flow using these, ie this code:

```
int x;
if (<some condition>)
    x = 1;
else
    x = 2;
```

may be coded using the ternary operator as:

```
int x = <some condition> ? 1 : 2;
```